# How do I extend a class in Rails using a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got the following I've pasted into my user model:

```
module ClassMethods
  Devise::Models.config(self, :email_regexp, :password_length)
end
```

I want to do something like `self.extend ClassMethods` in my User model, but I can't quite seem to get it right. I want to make these methods from devise accessible directly in my User model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ActiveSupport::Concern` for this. In the module that should be used to extend a class you insert:

```
module ModuleName
     extend ActiveSupport::Concern
     ....
     ....
     ....
     module ClassMethods
           # the Class Methos you want to add to other Classes here
     end

     module InstanceMethods
           # the instance Methods you want to add to other classes here
     end
end
```

And then eht only thing you need to do is `include` it in the `Model` you want to extend!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     include ModuleName
end
```

Thats it. For more info have a look at apidock => ActiveSupport::Concern!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just:

```
require 'my_module'
include MyModule::ClassMethods
```

Comment: I don't this is quite right; you're right to point out these come in gems, but I think this will extend the parent class from which was included, not the class I'm in.

Comment: I think the second one does, though. The first one is triggered when the module is "included" in another class... but the second version (I think) just says "start evaluating at class level"... but of course, some more googling might help :)

Comment: Hmmm - thinking about your question i may have misread the intent. You just need a way to include some other module in yours. Have you tried the above? if not - can you give us the full error message you get when it fails th way you've got it now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got everything right but if you want add functionality to the class when the module is included you can use `self.included`

```
module ClassMethods

  def self.included( base )
    Devise::Models.config( base, :email_regexp, :password_length )
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can think is:

```
module Devisable
  def included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      Devise::Models.config(self, :email_regexp, :password_length)
    end
  end
end
```

class_eval is a good way of inserting code and keeping you from messing around with `base` or `ClassMethods`.