# Why isn't my rails 4 helper working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, self, view-helpers

I have a helper module for my home page with two methods that do the same thing:

```
module HomeHelper
    def parsed_text(tweet)
        auto_link (tweet).gsub(/(@\w+)/, %Q{<a href="http://twitter.com/\\1">\\1</a>})
    end
    def other_parsed_text
        self.auto_link.gsub(/(@\w+)/, %Q{<a href="http://twitter.com/\\1">\\1</a>})
    end
end
```

In my view this works:

```
<%= parsed_text(tweet.text) %>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<%= tweet.text.other_parsed_text %>
```

I get a `NoMethodError at /
undefined method other_parsed_text`. Isn't `self` the caller of the method inside of my helper method?

What am I doing wrong? I want the second style of calling methods with a `.` notation to work too. How do I do that?

Comment: Why was I marked down? Is the question not proper?

Answer (score 2):

This does not work because you didnt extend the class that `tweet.text` is of. You can use [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) if you want to extend some class. What you are doing now is provding some methods that can be called with parameters.

// I posted an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504448/1001324

Comment: Some sample code would really help. How do I extend my Tweet class with activesupport? Which class, module or file would I do this in?