# Rails - where and how to set values for Active Record models - controllers or models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In keeping with rails best practice design pattern - skinny controllers, fat models - where and how should one set the default values for active record models based on controller actions. For instance, take the below action to release a car. Please suggest a more maintainable way if not outlined. Is it over engineering to develop a custom release_car save method?

```
#### OPTION #1 ####
  # controller
  def release
    # scope available is 'car_status_code = 'A'
    @car = Car.available.where(id: params.require(:id),
                                        client_id: current_user.client_id).last

    @car.car_updated_at_user_id = current_user.id 

    # are these considered 'business logic' that go into model???
    @car.car_release_date = Date.current 
    @car.car_status_code = 'R'

    # car_release_update_params is about 7 strong params 
    if @car.update_attributes(car_release_update_params)
      render json: "Car released", status: :ok
    else
      render json: @car.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  #### OPTION #2 ####
  # controller
  def release
    # scope available is 'car_status_code = 'A'
    @car = Car.available.where(id: params.require(:id),
                                        client_id: current_user.client_id).last

    # car_release_update_params is about 7 param fields
    if @car.release_car(car_release_update_params)
      render json: "Car released", status: :ok
    else
      render json: @car.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

  end

  #model
  def release_car(params)

    if self.car_status_code != 'A'
      errors.add(:base, 'Car must be in Available status to be released') 
      return false
    end

    self.car_status_code = 'A'
    self.car_release_date = Date.current #timezone friendly 

    #assign values for other fields based on params hash
    .....
    self.save

  end
```

Comment: the best practice is not *skinny controllers, fat models*, but *busyness controllers*, some logic of which can be moved to helpers, *skinny models*, and *fat libraries*. So, move `#release_car` to controller's helper, and use it from there. and have a cleaned up model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I whould always suggest to put your logic to the model.

MVC (Model View Controller) is a principle that seperates the data and logic (Model) from the presentation of the objects (View) and the controlling Unit bewteen them (Controller).

So its better practice to do stuff by calling methods from the model then changing various attributes from the controller but that doesnt mean that all the methods have to be defined in the model directly. Just declare your "core" methods in the model and put the other "surrounding" methods in modules that extend the class. Name these modules semanticly so you dont get confused about where to find your code. You can do this using `ActiveSupport::Convern`. I explained the usage here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504448/1001324

This has one big upside when it comes to polymorphic associations. You can declare methods for many models using one polymorphic association in a single file and extend all classes using this association.